# Recieving all N/A when filtering with R

Tags: r

When I am trying to filter my dataset to include rows only where dayname=Monday, I receive feedback but it is all N/A. My dataset has no N/A included. Could someone please help? below is my code.

```
install.packages("mlbench")
install.packages("AppliedPredictiveModeling")
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071) # misc library including skewness function
library("mlbench")
data(difference)
str(difference)
rm(list=ls())
setwd("~/Documents")
diff = read.csv('difference.csv',header = T)
attach(diff)
dayname<-diff$dayname
filter(diff, dayname =="Monday")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the `filter` function from `dplyr`, have you tried removing the line where you assign the values from the `dayname` column to the `dayname` variable?

```
diff = read.csv("difference.csv", header = T)
filter(diff, dayname == "Monday")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `dayname<-diff$dayname`

You can do this in many ways

Using base `R`:

```
diff <- read.csv("difference.csv", header = T)
subset(diff, dayname =="Monday")
```

Using `filter` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(diff, dayname =="Monday")
```

Using `filter` in pipe:

```
diff %>%
  filter(dayname =="Monday")
```